# Adding new data based on maximum duplicates and number of minimum counts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data_list = [['Name', 'Fruit'],
              ['Abel', 'Apple'],
              ['Abel', 'Pear'],
              ['Abel', 'Coconut'],
              ['Abel', 'Pear'],
              ['Benny', 'Apple'],
              ['Benny', 'Apple'],
              ['Cain', 'Apple'],
              ['Cain', 'Coconut'],
              ['Cain', 'Pear'],
              ['Cain', 'Lemon'],
              ['Cain', 'Orange']]

record_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list[1:], columns = data_list[0])
record_df
```

I am trying to create 2 extra data column in a pandas dataframe.

1. Count of the highest duplicate.
2. Count of fruits with the lowest duplicate.

So the end results would be

```
Name | Count of Highest Duplicate | Count of fruits with lowest duplicate
Abel | 2 | 2
Benny | 2 | 1
Cain | 1 | 5
```

I have tried

```
record_df.groupby('Name')['Fruit'].nunique().reset_index()
```

and

```
record_df.groupby('Name')['Fruit'].value_counts()
```

but am unsure where to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value_counts` then `groupby`:

```
out = df.value_counts(['Name', 'Fruit']).groupby(level='Name') \
        .agg(**{'Count of Highest Duplicate': 'max',
                'Count of fruits with lowest duplicate': lambda x: sum(x==x.min())})
print(out)

# Output
       Count of Highest Duplicate  Count of fruits with lowest duplicate
Name                                                                    
Abel                            2                                      2
Benny                           2                                      1
Cain                            1                                      5
```

Comment: Thank you! Will check this answer out as well!

Comment: Nice @Corralien ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crosstab` and standard operations:

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(record_df['Name'], record_df['Fruit'])
df2 = df2.where(df2.ne(0))

pd.DataFrame({'max': df2.max(axis=1),
              'count(min)': df2.eq(df2.min(axis=1), axis=0).sum(axis=1)},
             index=df2.index)
```

output:

```
       max  count(min)
Name                  
Abel     2           2
Benny    2           1
Cain     1           5
```

Comment: Thank you! The output is exactly what I am looking for. Now to break down what .crosstab / .eq / .where / .astype does :)

Comment: @kalystat actually I just read the question again and I have a doubt on what exactly is the first column, can you clarify? I used the max

Comment: I think Max is correct. I am trying to find out the highest number of a type of fruit 1 person has and the end result is not the object/ string but an integer